# Changing the hostname of a VM in VCloud DIrector using Chef's knife-vcloud plugin

Tags: chef-infra, knife, vcloud-director-rest-api

I am using chef's knife-vcloud plugin. https://github.com/astratto/knife-vcloud
I am able to create a new vm, using an existing catalog with the given documentation by,
knife vc vapp create MyorgVDC-Tier1 chefnode2 "Just Created node2" WhAtEvEr-Id-tO-bE-SeEn

When I start the vm it by default takes the hostname that is given to the catalog. I tried modifying it by 
knife vc vm set info --name ChefNewNode WhAtEvEr-Id-tO-bE-SeEn --vapp MyvApp_Chef centos
I want to change the hostname as per the role of the machine. At present I see this output. How do I change the hostname of the machine?

[root@chefworkstation ~]# knife vc vm show WhAtEvEr-Id-tO-bE-SeEn
Note: --vapp and --vdc not specified, assuming VM is an ID
VM Name: ChefNewNode
OS Name: CentOS 4/5/6 (64-bit)
Status: running

Cpu
Number of Virtual CPUs  1 virtual CPU(s)

Memory
Memory Size             512 MB of memory

Disks
Hard disk 1             16384 MB
Hard disk 2             16384 MB

Networks
MyorgNet-Router

Index                 0
Ip                    192.168.0.117
External ip
Is connected          true
Mac address           10:20:30:40:50:0f
Ip allocation mode    MANUAL

Guest Customizations
Enabled                 true
Admin passwd enabled    true
Admin passwd auto       false
Admin passwd
Reset passwd required   false

Computer name           centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this by changing the guest computer name. Note that the VM must be turned off to change any guest customization.

Command to change guest computer name:

knife vc vm config guest <*vm name*> --vapp <*vapp name*> --vdc <*vdc name*> --guest-computer-name <*guest computer name*> --admin-passwd <*root password*>

Answer (score 0):

The `--name` you are passing is the Chef node name, not the hostname. If you want to change the hostname, you'll need to write/use a recipe that modifies `/etc/hostname` and runs some commands to persist. For example: https://github.com/3ofcoins/chef-cookbook-hostname